# Did Cyrano de Bergerac's space ship have retro-rockets?

Tags: physics

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/29980/12102) I cite and quote some surprising information; that the real Cyrano de Bergerac (not the one in the play) had written of using a rocket ship to go to the Moon circa 1650.

As strange as it sounds, I'm asking if Cyrano de Bergerac's conceptualization of a space ship include retro-rockets, or at least *some propulsive method to decelerate* (slow down)?

Comment: suggestions for better tagging are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say, seeing as his little [essay](http://www.photonics.umbc.edu/Menyuk/Schwartz_VOYAGE-TO-THE-MOON.pdf) about going to the moon was almost certainly a combination of fantasy and satire.  Consider his landing:

> After falling a long time, or so I presume, the violence of my fall
>   having kept me from noticing it, the next thing I can recall is
>   finding myself under a tree, tangled in three or four rather thick
>   branches that I had shattered by my fall, with my face smeared with an
>   apple that had smashed into it.

Comment: Hmm... that's does seem to suggest that it's not likely, thanks!

Comment: I've cited your research [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31179/12102) I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @uhoh  No problem.  Make me famous  :-)